# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after workspace was moved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a few projects that were developed by a different developer.
He won't work on it anymore, so I'm supposed to take over his work.
I copied his whole workspace into mine.

Eclipse and Maven is used.

Everything seems to be fine, until I try to run the application and get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] on compiling verticle site.webgui.webapp.Starter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/gas/toolbox/Utils
    at site.webgui.webapp.Starter.start (Starter.java:57)
    at io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle.start (AbstractVerticle.java:111)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$159 (DeploymentManager.java:429)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$16 (ContextImpl.java:335)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run (NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.gas.toolbox.Utils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.IsolatingClassLoader.loadClass (IsolatingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at site.webgui.webapp.Starter.start (Starter.java:57)
    at io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle.start (AbstractVerticle.java:111)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$159 (DeploymentManager.java:429)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$16 (ContextImpl.java:335)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run (NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] Error in deployment
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/gas/toolbox/Utils
    at site.webgui.webapp.Starter.start (Starter.java:57)
    at io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle.start (AbstractVerticle.java:111)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$159 (DeploymentManager.java:429)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$16 (ContextImpl.java:335)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run (NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.gas.toolbox.Utils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.IsolatingClassLoader.loadClass (IsolatingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at site.webgui.webapp.Starter.start (Starter.java:57)
    at io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle.start (AbstractVerticle.java:111)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$159 (DeploymentManager.java:429)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$16 (ContextImpl.java:335)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run (NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run (SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

web_gui_site is the project and toolbox is the one that's referenced.

From what I understand, it seems like the classpath works fine while compiling, but throws the exception in runtime.

---

What I tried:

1. As per the previous developers suggestion I used mvn compile, mvn package and mvn clean install on the Toolbox project and then updated web_gui_sts Project via maven -> Update Project... with following options set: Update dependencies, Update project configuration from pom.xml, Refresh workspace resources from local filesystem, Clean projects.
2. Disabling and re-enabling Maven Dependency Management
3. Deleting .classpath, .settings and .project and running mvn eclipse:eclipse on the project again.
4. Checked if every .class file is properly created within the .jar for Toolbox, recreating it and building the project anew.

---

When I go to Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Project the Toolbox Project is properly set.

It works just fine on the previous machine, with the same settings. So I assume it breaks somewhere when I copy the files over to my workspace.

The Question now, what exactly breaks and how do I fix it?

---

EDIT1: okay, once I stopped tunnel visioning directly on the bright read error message I found that there's another warning thrown:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 (file:/C:/Users/<user>/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.0.31.Final/netty-common-4.0.31.
Final.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I guess it's another thing I'll have to look into.

Edit2: Okay, that was easy Fix for that Edit, just an issue with jdk9. Now it's running with jdk8 without that warning.

---

Solution: As mentioned below in the comments, apparently the newer maven version I was using was having issues with it. I used 3.5.2, which didn't work, but 3.3.9 works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

The problem was based on a different verion of maven used in the development enviroments.

---

original hint, check a few things:

- what happens at "site.webgui.webapp.Starter.start (Starter.java:57)"
- click on your project -> build path -> libraries
- open the maven dependencies and other if exist: are there any missing jars shown?
- de.gas.toolbox.Utils belongs to Toolbox-Project I guess, try to find out in the original setup how it is referenced
- in Eclipse you can add Project-Dependencies -> click right on your project -> properties -> project references (working with maven not the best solution I think)
- try to create a parent-child maven project, sounds like this would be the best way, there are many tutorial out there:
  https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/

Comment: at Starter.java:57 he's getting the config.json that mainly just sets the port and some settings, but it's the same on the other machine.

No missing jars shown. Even the Toolbox Project is in the maven dependencies.

I don't exactly know how to answer that question. The Toolbox Project is added in the classpath under Configure Build Path... -> Projects.

Adding Project-Dependencies doesn't help either.

Gonna try the parent-child thing now.

Comment: You said it happens after starting the app, so it looks like a class is compiled at runtime, because of: "[ERROR] on compiling..." How do you start your application? Maybe it is a problem with the vertx framework you're using.

Comment: I use mvn vertx:hot to start it locally and have a look at it before uploading. That's where it fails. Strangely enough, I just copied the created .jars (done with mvn package) to the live machine and it works there without a hitch. So I also assume it has something to do with vertx or my local machine, so I'm currently looking into that.

Comment: Apparently there's another WARNING I've missed, I added it to the original post.

Comment: I guess you miss something in your classpath to run your app or if you build a fat jar, something is not included.

Comment: Checked the fat jar. The class is definitely included. Classpath, at least in eclipse, looks fine, too.

Comment: It may be included in the jar, but it seems to me the classloader of vertx cannot load it: at io.vertx.core.impl.IsolatingClassLoader.loadClass (IsolatingClassLoader.java:67) Maybe vertx needs some additional settings like here:https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/issues/1252 ? Do you have the same vertx version on all enviroments dev, live etc? Another appraoch: is this file config.json really readable at runtime? Can you proof that?

Comment: I could hang myself for the solution... apparently the newer maven version I was using was having issues with it. I used 3.5.2, which didn't work, but 3.3.9 works fine... Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Clean/build the project. Also, check the location of the libraries in the project in case they were not imported into the folder of the project.

Comment: Everything's where it should be, that's what's weird about it.
I removed and added the project from the classpath multiple times.